# Approximative sorting algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, machine-learning, prediction

I've developed a predictive model using a deep neural network.

This model aims at comparing 2 inputs :

```
- if input 1 is better than input 2 then model returns 1
- if input 2 is better than input 1 then model returns 2
```

I trained the model on 100 inputs and now, I want to compare a new_input to all of these 100 inputs in order to know approximatively how good new_input is.

My goal is to be able to approximate the rank of the new_input. For example : I would like to say, after having trained and used my model, the new_input is approximatively the 12th best of all 101 inputs.

My problem is : when i'm using the model to compare the new_input to all of 100 inputs, some results are inconsistent.

Let's look an example :

```
- Inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] (here, there is only 10 inputs, not 100 as before)
- new_input = 8
- Model returns : 
8 > 1 : OK
8 > 2 : OK
8 > 3 : OK
8 > 4 : OK
8 < 5 : NOT OK
8 < 6 : NOT OK
8 > 7 : OK
8 < 8 : OK
8 < 9 : OK
8 > 10 : NOT OK
```

How could i do to know how to rank the new_input (= 8) properly ?

PS : of course, in my real case, inputs are not numbers, but matrixes :)

Comment: Not sure what the exact question here is, but sounds like the rank you are looking for is the total number of `OK`s (or `NOT OK`s, depending on how you define "rank") plus 1.

Comment: Sorry for my approximative question ^^ but yes exactly, I have to determine which line is "OK", and which is "NOT". My problem is that, for new_entry, I cannot be sure of this because I do not know its value (here "8") : it is what I want to determine !

Comment: What do you know then? Please clarify your question by posting a sample input and the expected output for that input.